# APA: How to cite an application report or an application note

Tags: apa

I'm working on an engineering project and lots of the design decisions I've made are based on application notes or application reports made by manufacturers, like this one:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva057/slva057.pdf

How can I cite this kind of sources?

Comment: Hahahah, I was looking this up to cite EXACTLY the same application note you wanted to cite! What are the odds?

Comment: @DIMscene which project are you working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APA Publication Manual (6th ed., 2009) gives several reference examples for technical and research reports (in section 7.03, pp. 205-206) which suggest the following format:

- Rogers, E. (1999). *Understanding buck power stages in switchmode power supplies* (Application Report No. SLVA057). Retrieved from Texas Instruments website: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva057/slva057.pdf